# How to test react list item move with react-testing-library

Tags: react-testing-library

Try to test a simple component which renders a list of string and each item will move to top when clicked.

```js
const Component = p => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(p.data)
  const moveToTop = from => {
    const nextData = [...data]
    const target = nextData.splice(from, 1)[0]
    nextData.unshift(target)
    setData(nextData)
  }
  console.log(data, 'data')
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((d, i) => (
        <li
          aria-label="li"
          key={d}
          onClick={() => {
            moveToTop(i)
          }}
        >
          {d}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

// ... test ...

test('move element', async () => {
  render(<Component data={['a', 'b', 'c']} />)
  const liArr = screen.getAllByLabelText('li')
  expect(liArr.length).toBe(3)
  expect(liArr[0].textContent).toBe('a')
  fireEvent.click(liArr[2])
  expect(liArr[0].textContent).toBe('c')
})
```

In [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-noyce-23vwm?file=/src/index.test.js),log shows that clickEvent set data successfully, but last assert failed.
I know that react re-render costs time but i also notice that `@testing-library/react` has wrapped `act` for its render api. After search github issues and stackoverflow, i still got stuck in this test case.

Need your help, any doc and samples will make sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `li` ordering changes but you are not asserting on the new structure. Do another `screen.getAllByLabelText('li')` after the click event and assert on that.